# Chrome extension working on two tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a Chrome extension that retrieves some content from the DOM of the current tab, then opens a new tab, and performs an operation on this new tab using the previously retrieved content.

I am attempting to use callbacks to perform this sequence, but I can't figure out a proper way to do it. Now I am able to execute the first script, and get the content from the current tab DOM: what I still can't do is passing this content to the second script, utilities2.js, to be executed on the new tab.

Here's my current code:

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
    <head><title>Extension</title></head>  
<body>  
    <button id="clickactivity">Click here</button>  
    <script src="popup.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    var tempStorage;
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"}, function(results){
                tempStorage = results[0];
            });

            chrome.tabs.create({"url":"http://www.google.com","selected":true}, function(tab) {
            });

        });

}

document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

contentScript.js

```
function execContentScript() {

    var code = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
    return code;

}

execContentScript();
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My extension",  
    "description": "My extension",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>","activeTab"],  

    "browser_action": { 
        "default_popup": "popup.html"  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the content in the local storage of Chrome extension and after navigating to next tab, you can get the content from local storage of Chrome.

The following code may help you in this case:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function() {
      console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
    });

    chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
      console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
    });
```

If you want to learn more about the local storage of Chrome, please read from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

---

**Edit:**

I think you don't have idea of background scripts in the Chrome extension. Background scripts which have highest privileges to run the Chrome commands.

The complete workflow will be as follows:

- popup.js is included as script
- When you click button, injectTheScript function will be called from popup.js
- Then it will get the element id from page and then send the request to background.js
- Then background.js will save the value to Chrome storage
- Then background.js will create new tab
- After successful creation of tab, it will execute callback function and get the value from storage of Chrome

---

**The following is the complete code of working extension:**

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "My extension",
"description": "My extension",
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>","activeTab","storage"],

"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
}
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head><
        title>Extension</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="clickactivity">Click here</button>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function injectTheScript() {
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

    var code="abc";
    //var code = document.getElementById('textarea').value;

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "navigate",value:code}, function(response) {
        console.log('code saved to local storage');

    });

});

}

document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

if (request.type == "navigate"){

        chrome.storage.sync.set({key: request.value}, function() {

        console.log('Background got request for saving the code '+request.value+' to local storage');


        chrome.tabs.create({"url":"http://www.google.com","selected":true}, function( tab) {


            console.log('navigated to new tab');
            chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {

                console.log('new tab key is '+result.key);

            });


        });


    });

 }



});
```

You don't need utilities2.js and content_script.js.

I've tested the code and it's working according to your requirements.

You can not see the console output if anything is consoled in background page. To see the output on console (for anything in background), open the link chrome://extensions 
and click the button Background Page as following

[image: click]

A new window will appear as following

[image]

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please have a look on updated answer. Thanks

Comment: Please make sure that when you click the button in chrome extension,
then there must be a text box named as textarea.

Comment: Please share the updated code. Can't say exactly about it

Comment: On which page are you clicking the button of extension?
Is it  html file?